# ion-select set start value

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to set the initial data displayed for an Ion-select.
I have narrowed it down to this simplest example although I have it in another situation too. Most of the questions here seem to be using [ngModel] which I don't think I need because I am using an Angular Reactive form.
The html is:

```
  <form [formGroup]="userDetailsForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

 ... some stuff
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
  <ion-select placeholder="Select One" formControlName="Gender">
    <ion-select-option value="3">Female</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="2">Male</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="1">Other</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="0">Prefer Not to Say</ion-select-option>
 </ion-select>
</ion-item>

 ... more stuff
<ion-button expand="full" type="submit">Submit</ion-button>

</form>
```

My code is:

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.userDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    ... some stuff
     Gender: [],
    });
    this.userService.getUserServer().subscribe (user => {
      // console.log('Patching the form');
      this.userDetailsForm.patchValue(user);
      ... other irrelevant code
    },
      error => this.helper.showAlert('We cant connect to the server at the moment msg is:' + error)
    );

  }
```

The field is always showing empty (with the placeholder as shown), and I have also tried removing the placeholder and using:

```
      <ion-select value ="3" formControlName="Gender">
```

No matter what I try it won't show the default or what I set it to...
Sorry if this is obvious but what am I missing?
Many thanks.

**EDIT**
I have tried removing the **formControlName="Gender"** part of it and now it works. Except of course it won't be part of the reactive form... I think this smells a bit buggy - I will continue to dig, meanwhile, any further thoughts welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted this as an answer in case anyone else fall into this.
I am not sure if its due to an early release issue with the ionic 4 I have but I fixed it by re-ordering the ion-select line.

```
 <ion-select placeholder="Select One" value = {{userDetailsForm.value.Gender}} formControlName="Gender" >
    <ion-select-option value="3">Female</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="2">Male</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="1">Other</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="0">Prefer Not to Say</ion-select-option>
 </ion-select>
```

placing the 'value = xxx' before the 'formControlName = yyyy' fixed it.
This is a weird one...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add already selected empty option with your placeholder:

```
<ion-select formControlName="Gender">
            <ion-select-option value="" selected="selected" hidden="hidden">Choose here</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="3">Female</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="2">Male</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="1">Other</ion-select-option>
            <ion-select-option value="0">Prefer Not to Say</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I saw what you put there, and didn't understand how it could work, so I tried it and it doesn't. What you put there isn't a placeholder, but another option. Which duly appears in the list as another option. Just for further clarity the field is still blank at start up. - Are you using Ionic 4? does this work in some other version?